# Socket check TCP/IP connection exists and shorten timeout

Tags: objective-c, sockets, adhoc

I am trying to connect my iOS application to a printer on a adhoc network, I need to check the connection is open and valid before sending anything to the printer, How can I achieve this? currently I am doing the following 
    CFReadStreamRef     readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef    writeStream;

```
readStream = NULL;
writeStream = NULL;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)IPADDRESS, NUM_PORT,NULL ,&writeStream );

if(writeStream)
{
    //inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
    oStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    //[iStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [oStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    //[iStream setDelegate:delegate];
    [oStream setDelegate:delegate];
    //[iStream open];
    [oStream open];
}
```

and

```
   int bytesWritten;
   int bytesTotal = [data length];

   bytesWritten = [oStream write:[data bytes] maxLength: bytesTotal];
   NSLog(@"Bytes Written To Printer : %d",bytesWritten);
```

but it is always going in and writeStream is never null so I am unable to stop it trying to push data to the socket.

~Edit - Maybe I'm best rephrasing my question, How can I stop it from hanging for 30+ seconds until it realises there is no connection?

Comment: What protocol are you using to talk to the printer?

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry I'm not quite sure what you mean, I am just sending raw data to a printer via NSOutputStream to an Ip and port.

Comment: You aren't using IPP?  I don't understand how a printer can respond to raw data.

Comment: Sorry I cannot be more of any help I am afraid all I know is that I just send a output stream which contains string to a port and it is printing it out (When it is connected of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check the connection is open and valid before sending anything to the printer, How can I achieve this?

By sending something to the printer. The only way to detect a connection problem in TCP is to do some I/O with it.

Comment: Ok...Maybe I'm best rephrasing my question, How can I stop it from hanging for 30+ seconds until it realises there is no connection?

Comment: After looking into this further I Used Reachabillity to ping the ip first before trying to send data thanks